# how to make a d triangle in blender?

Tags: rendering

[image]I am trying o make a pie piece in blender but after using sub surf modifier it changed so I used edge crease in order to to make it in it's original form but it's not working . Can anyone of you here help me how to do it correctly? I am adding a image for your reference. Kindly help.[image]

Comment: hello, could you please show another angle? it's hard to understand what you're trying to do and how your object looks like

Comment: I just added another picture @moonboots kindly check

Comment: just change subsurf modifier to simple

Comment: edge crease should work but you can also create some bevels, select all in Edit mode, press Ctrl B and drag your mouse, press + or - to add some segments to the bevels

Comment: ok, moonboots, show me how this works. I tried and got: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3nEd.png (subsurf 3)

Comment: if you select all the edges and crease it will round all the edges, but I'm not sure that this is what he wants, it's not clear to me  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a simple mesh, so I shall provide a simple answer, and encourage you to experiment. Ultimately it is about constraining our edges with bevels before subdividing.

We have our triangle:
[image]

Select our edges, and set the mean bevel weight to 0.01
[image]

Use a bevel modifier, set the limit method to weight, and adjust the amount to a value you are happy with (this will vary with mesh size, face size etc...)

[image]

Finally subdivide your mesh with a sub-division modifier

[image]

You may need to adjust the bevel amount and segments to get the desired edge profile, and perhaps add a bit more geometry to your mesh

Comment: thank you  @moonboots for your help that really helped a lot

Comment: thank you  @james for your help that really helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

[image]

maybe i misunderstood you, but if you want to make a piece of cake i would add a plane, delete one vertex, extrude z axis.

Then add bevel modifier and shade smooth.

result:

[image]